# What is the best way to use H2 protocol with nest js application?

Tags: nestjs, h2

For the nest js application what would be the best way we can use H2 protocol ?

Comment: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8773

Comment: Thank you for the link by the way  I raised that issue